# Best results of the year 2021

Tags: soft-question, math-history

I hope this is a valid question.

I want to know what were the most important papers, books or discoveries in the year.  I want a note on my blog but I am only informed on topics of interest to me and I would like a more general opinion.

Comment: Related MO thread: [Breakthroughs in mathematics in 2021](https://mathoverflow.net/q/412437)

Comment: [Quanta magazine](https://www.quantamagazine.org/) often has coverage of recent mathematical breakthroughs. [Here is their “2021 in math and computer science”](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-year-in-math-and-computer-science-20211223/) review article.

Comment: I am puzzled by the fact that the same question attracted 95 votes (so far) on MO and 3 close votes on MathStackExchange (without any comment, as usual). Are the readers of this site really interested in mathematics?

Comment: It often seems to me that many of them are not interested in mathematics so much as they are interested in closing and deleting articles.Wikipedia has a similar population of people who are not actually interested in writing an encyclopedia and who find it more rewarding to dismantle the part that has already been written.